# No iostream for makefile compilation but fine with regular compilation

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a file like this: (p1.c)

```
  1 #include <iostream>                                                                                                
  5
  6 int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  7    std::cout << "No iostream\n";
  8    return 0;
  9 }
```

And I try to compile with a simple makefile like this:

```
  1 app: p1.o                                                                                                          
  2     g++ p1.o -o p1
  3
  4 clean:
  5     rm *.o p1 p2
```

Running `make` yields this:

```
p1.c:1:10: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
 #include <iostream>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'p1.o' failed
make: *** [p1.o] Error 1
```

But running `g++ p1.c` works fine, no issues.

Am I doing something wrong in the make file? I've had no other troubles with libraries besides iostream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only specified a Makefile rule to link the object file to an executable. You haven't actually specified a rule to compile the source code file to an object file.

Therefore `make` will try to use an implicit rule to build the object file `p1.o` from `p1.c`.

Because `p1.c` has the file ending `.c` it will assume that the file is C source code and call `cc` to compile it, which should be a C compiler, not a C++ compiler.

In C there is no `<iostream>` and so the compilation fails.

Change the file name from `p1.c` to `p1.cpp` or `p1.cxx` or `p1.cc` or some of the other conventional file endings for C++. It is not only confusing to `make`, but also confusing to other programmers, when a `.c` file doesn't actually contain C source code.

Comment: Yes the cpp was it. Sorry I tried to format the code and ended up accidentally deleting the  int from main.